# running `go test` in one package results creating unwanted log folder

Tags: go, testing

I'm trying to make a unit test for one package in a complex codebase
but every time I try run `go test`, it results in making unwanted log folder.
I assume in one of imports' imports' imports has init() that creating the log folder(Am I right?)..but I don't know how to track it!

Is there anything I can do in this situation?

Comment: «I assume in one of imports' imports' imports has init() that creating the log folder(Am I right?)» quite possibly yes. Consider running `go list -deps ./package` to get the package's dependency graph and inspect the code of the suspects in that list. Please note that some packages might dabble with the `testing` infrastructure itself and stick the logging logic there; start with `go doc testing.M` to explore that possibility. Well, and after all the code under test might just do logging itself—that's something to explore, too.

Comment: …and while we're at it: is the `log` folder ends up being empty? If, on the contrary, it contains files with some "stable" (the same on each run) names or names following a certain pattern (such as a timestamp), you might get away with creative `grep`ping of the contents of the deps. Note that if the deps are Go modules, you still can grep their code because they are just ZIP archives under `~/.cache/go-build`, and you can know where they are located by peering at the output produced by your `go test` run when you pass it the `-x` command-ine option.